# Do characters in Lawrence Block's books ever meet each other?

Tags: intertextuality, lawrence-block

Do characters in Lawrence Block's books ever meet each other? For example, Matthew Scudder and Bernie Rhodenbarr, do they know each other?

Comment: Welcome to Literature SE! (You can take our short [tour] to find out more about how this site works, if you're not already aware.) This seems like an interesting question; I haven't been able to find an answer yet.